# Skip First Line When Combining txt Files with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script to combine multiple txt files in a folder to an output file, but I need to remove the header row.  I've tried the following:

```
$outFile = new-item -path 'combined\combined.txt' -itemtype file -force


$inFiles = @(Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt)


Get-Content $inFiles[0] -First 1 | Set-Content -Encoding Utf8 $outFile


 Get-ChildItem  -Recurse -Include  "*.txt" | get-content | Select -Skip 1 |
    Out-File -Append -encoding ASCII $outFile
```

I've also tried looping but would run into errors about the file being in use or the powershell script just stopping and not combining all files

```
    foreach ($file in $inFiles) {
  $from = Get-Content -path $file | 
  Select-Object -Skip 1  
  Add-Content $outFile -value $from }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating this ... this should be enough:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | 
Select-Object -First 1 |
ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content -Path $_.FullName |
    Select-Object -First 1
} | 
Out-File -FilePath 'combined\combined.txt'

Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt |
ForEach-Object {
    Get-Content -Path $_.FullName |
    Select-Object -Skip 1
} | 
Out-File -FilePath 'combined\combined.txt' -Append
```

The first snippet creates the output file with only the headers taken from the first input file.
The second snippet gets the all lines except of the first one from all input files.

Are you sure it is about txt files? If it'd be about CSV files with the same headers it would be easier. ;-)

Comment: Apologies for not being more clear in the original post.  I need to keep 1 header row in the resulting file.  This works with removing all headers.

Comment: updated my answer ...

Comment: I wish it was CSV files!  They are all pipe delimited text files.  Thank you for the help!

One note, I found that the resulting file was double the size of the total of the source files.  It looks like it has to do with encoding.  I tried adding -encoding ascii but that returned chinese characters.  this line at the top fixed it:
$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'ASCII'

Comment: The pipe `|` is a valid delimiter for CSV files as well. Where do these files come from? There may be a way to build them in the desired way in the first place. It might help when you share some sample data from one of the files.